# Send Multiple Custom Field Values Through the URL

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Basically, I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/) to add an action to the `pre_get_posts` and create a custom meta_query so I can alter the query within the URL and display babies,children and home books like so:

> http://website.com/books/?type=babies,children,home

I'm using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for my custom fields and my custom field is called 'type' and is set up in WordPress as a Checkbox Field, so it accepts multiple values.

For the life of me, I can't work out how to get it to display the queried posts.

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if( is_admin() ) { return; }

$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
    if( !empty($_GET['type']) ) {               
        $type = explode('|', $_GET['type']);    
        $meta_query[] = array(                          
            'key'       => 'type',
            'value'     => $type,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
    }

$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query); // update the meta query args
return; // always return
}
```

Using `'compare' => 'LIKE'` just returns random posts, using `IN` returns a blank results page.

Not sure if it's to do with my `$_GET['type']` parameter, which is supposed to be string.

Any help with solving this is appreciated. I'm on my 5th cup of coffee and the evening isn't looking promising.

**archive.book.php**

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'book',
'posts_per_page'    => 10,
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {

    $wp_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
}
```

This normal loop:

```
<?php 
print_r( $wp_query->request );
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

outputs this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS blISt3rs871o_posts.ID FROM blISt3rs871o_posts WHERE 1=1 AND blISt3rs871o_posts.post_type = 'book' AND (blISt3rs871o_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR blISt3rs871o_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY blISt3rs871o_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Removed 'compare'   => 'IN',  you dont need it if your fields not a number or something to compare.

Comment: Removing `'compare' => 'IN'`still results in a blank page.

Comment: Change explode('|' to explode(',' becouse in your url is , symbol not |

Comment: I've changed it to `explode('|'`but that still results in a blank results page.

Comment: explode need to be ',' sybol. If not, your get parametrs dont come into in code. You can see on orginal ACF code, that they have a explode(','

Comment: Sorry, I mean I've changed it to `explode(','`, but still a blank page. If my `$_GET` param isn't coming into the page, how I can I fix that?

Comment: Test it. You also need explode fix and add a post type, for example: ` 'post_type' => 'building',`  if post type is not defined then you get a white page.

Comment: I'm defining the `post_type` in my `wp_query` argument for my loop. It's weird because if I change my custom field ('type') to a different custom field ('format'), the URL query works.

Comment: Check a answers code.

Comment: Add `print_r( $wp_query->request );` to your template, this will show you the SQL query being sent to the database. Copy whatever that outputs, edit your question, and paste it here so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: With @Brian Richards `functions.php` code below, or my original `functions.php` code above?

Comment: with Brian's code. also note, his code is modifying the main query, so you just want to run the normal loop, not create an additional query in the template.

Comment: @Milo I've added the output of `print_r( $wp_query->request );` to the original question.

Comment: according to that query, there is no meta query happening there at all.

Comment: @Milo That's strange. Why could that be happening? I've also added my loop to the original question to make sure I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: did you remove the query that overwrites `$wp_query` -`$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );`?

Comment: @Milo Yup! My template is literally a header, a footer and the normal loop above. No `$wp_query`in sight. Would you mind using the chat so I could go through this with you? I'd really appreciate it if you're able to...

Comment: @realph Please don't start a comment explosion here. Put updates as [edit]s into your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, keep in mind that `pre_get_posts` is a hook that is run on every single query that WP runs, so be very, very careful when utilizing it. That said, it is absolutely the best tool for what you want to do, and certainly better than writing a separate custom query in the page template.

I've added some additional conditions to the start of this function to make sure it is abandoned early if the query is: not for the main loop, running on an admin page, or if the 'type' query string is not present. You should add a few more conditions here to restrict it even further, e.g. `if ( ! is_page( 'something' ) ) { return; }` or `if ( ! is_front_page() ) { return; }`.

That said, here is some sample code:

```
/**
 * Add custom meta filter to main query on any page.
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 *
 * @param  object $query WP Query object.
 */
function wpse129223_custom_meta_query( $query ) {

    // If not on the main query, or on an admin page, bail here
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // If 'type' isn't being passed as a query string, bail here
    if ( empty( $_GET['type'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the existing meta query, cast as array
    $meta_query = (array) $query->get('meta_query');

    // Convert 'type' into an array of types
    $types = explode( ',', $_GET['type'] );

    // Ensure that types aren't empty
    if ( is_array( $types ) && ! empty( $types ) ) {

        // Build a meta query for this type
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'type',
            'value'   => $types,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );

        // Update the meta query
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    } 

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse129223_custom_meta_query' );
```

This expects the query string to be comma-separated, as you presented it in your example, website.com/whatever/?type=one,two,three. In your code example you were looking for a pipe character, which is what @Foxsk8 was getting at in his comments.

Comment: Did you not mean to pass `$types` in the meta query instead of `$_GET['type']`? It's also probably worth pointing out that `type` is not safe to pass via `GET` according to the [Reserved Terms section of `register_taxonomy` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms), though I can't get it to break anything query-wise.

Comment: Comma-seperated is fine with me! This is returning a blank page though, I've even tried passing `$types` in the meta query instead of `$_GET['type']`like @Milo said above, but still a blank page when doing `website.com/books/?type=children`.

Comment: I've added my post loop to the original question, if that helps.

Comment: Oops, good catch Milo. I see from your edit, @realph, that you're running an additional query on your archive page. My code sample will not work because it has been limited to target the main query for the page. Furthermore, you're actually doing double the work on this template now (WP runs the original query before in order to know what template to load and have the contents to populate it, then after the template is loaded you're running a query _again_ in order to load what you deem to be the relevant posts.

Comment: @BrianRichards So can I fix this by just using the normal loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code, that works.

```
<?php
     $type = explode(',', $_GET['type']);
     $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     $myquery = new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'building',
     'meta_query'=>array(
            array(
                'key' => 'type',
                'value' => $type,
            ),

        )

    ));
    if ($myquery->have_posts()) :
    while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, am I putting that code in my archive-book.php file? The code in my original post was from the `functions.php` file.

Comment: Create a file, for example page-filter.php in your theme folder. Put this code all into this file. In wordpress pages add new page and call it to Filter. Then use page.com/filter/?type=<your value>

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work. I've created a page called "Filter". Set up a new template for that page called "page-filter.php" and added the code to it, giving it a `'post_type' => 'book'`. But I'm just still just getting my header and footer but an empty page.